# remover dados de uma lista de objeto

Tags: c, c++, lista, stl

Estou com dificuldade para remover um objeto da lista de acordo com a um código.

Tentei fazer assim:

```
void turma::removeraluno (int matricula){
         // remover o aluno pelo codigo de matricula
    list<aluno>::iterator it;

for (it=lista.begin();it != lista.end();it++){

    if (it->getmatricula()== matricula) {
        lista.erase(it);

    } else{
        cout << "NAO ENCONTRADO "<<endl;
    }
}
```

Porem quando tento executar da erro de **buffer de memoria**. Já tentei com o remove também e não funciona

Answer (score 0):

você pode tentar.

```
for(int i;i<lista.size();i++){
    if(matricula==lista[i]){
        lista.erase(lista.begin()+i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Desse jeito ai deu o seguinte erro : error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘std::__cxx11::list<aluno>’ and ‘int’)|

Answer (score 0):

O seu erro resulta do fato de usar o iterador após ter chamado erase no mesmo. Isto resulta em comportamento indefinido.

Pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
void turma::removerAluno (int matricula)
{
    for (list<aluno>::iterator it = lista.begin(); it != lista.end(); ++it)
    {
       if (it->getmatricula() == matricula) 
       {
           //lista.erase(it);
           it = lista.erase(it);        
       } 
    }
}
```